# react native camera undefined

Tags: camera, react-native

```
use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

class BadInstagramCloneApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
          <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
        </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }
  takePicture() {
    this.camera.capture()
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    color: '#000',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 40
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => BadInstagramCloneApp);
```

I used the following steps to resolve the issue :
Delete the node_modules folder - rm -rf node_modules && npm install
Reset packager cache - rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-* or node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --reset-cache
Clear watchman watches - watchman watch-del-all
Recreate the project from scratch
But i still get an error.

Comment: have you configured the native side of the `react-native-camera` component?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have made the settings right, including running `$ react-native link react-native-camera` and others according the [documentation](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera).

Comment: Hi I am using : https://github.com/expo/expo-docs/blob/8dfaa440335ab2a70ce609b8c72d99246791598b/versions/unversioned/sdk/camera.md  repo and it gives me this error: `react-native link` can not be used in Create React Native App projects. If you need to include a library that relies on custom native code, you might have to eject first

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
var Camera = require('react-native-camera')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate it more? What's the problem OP had, why did it not work, how does this solve it...

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line:

```
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';
```

With this line:

```
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';
```

Change `<Camera></Camera>` tag to `<RNCamera></RNCamera>`.
Remove the aspect attribute from RNCamera tag.